# Django 2.0.7 Exception Type: OperationalError

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'products',]
Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

I'm getting this error on django adminstration site when I click on the save button. These are the errors:

`Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/`

`Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old`

Answer (score 1):

There is migrations missing,

Just do the following :

- django manage.py makemigrations
- django manage.py migrate